# laravel array update multiple rows with diffrent ids

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, insert-update

i am stuck in when i update multiple array value then each time update same value in diffrent ids like i have three fields like email,alert_level and select in select dropdoewn depends on alert_level choose option so now i want update all three fields but in stuck

here is my code

```
 if(!empty($requestData['edit_email']) && count($requestData['edit_email']) > 0){
    foreach($requestData['edit_email'] as $i => $list){
       $ids = array();
           $editdata = array();
           array_push($ids,$requestData['fid']);                    
           $editrow['email']=$requestData['edit_email'][$i];
           $editrow['phone'] = NULL;
           switch($requestData['edit_email_alert_level'][$i]){
              case 'client':
                   $editrow['alert_level'] = "client";
                   $editrow['client_id'] = (!empty($requestData['edit_locations'])) ? implode("," ,$requestData['edit_locations']) : NULL;
                   $editrow['salescenter_id'] = NULL;
                   $editrow['location_id'] = NULL; 
                   break;
              case 'salescenter':
                   $editrow['alert_level'] = "salescenter";
                   $editrow['client_id'] = (!empty($requestData['edit_locations'])) ? implode("," ,$requestData['edit_locations']) : NULL;
                   $editrow['salescenter_id'] = NULL;
                   $editrow['location_id'] = NULL;
                   break;
              case 'sclocation':
                   $editrow['alert_level'] = "sclocation";
                   $editrow['location_id'] = (!empty($requestData['edit_locations'])) ? implode("," ,$requestData['edit_locations']) : NULL; 
                   $editrow['client_id'] = NULL;
                   $editrow['salescenter_id'] = NULL;                            
                   break;
              default:
                   break;
             }                                  
          FraudAlert::whereIn('id',$ids)->update($editrow);
      }          
  }
```

here is this type of error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `fraud_alerts` set `0` = vandan@gmail.com, `updated_at` = 2020-10-15 10:20:32 where `id` in (228))

here is dd of $requestData

```
array:6 [▼
 "_token" => "sTUoBilbfwZfp0x6tSdZhB4S5YQTO7l0xlip0QzA"
 "clientId" => "102"
 "fid" => array:2 [▼
   0 => "228"
   1 => "231"
 ]
 "edit_email" => array:2 [▼
   0 => "van@gmail.com"
   1 => "demo@gmail.com"
 ]
 "edit_email_alert_level" => array:2 [▼
   0 => "sclocation"
   1 => "client"
 ]
 "edit_locations" => array:2 [▼
   0 => "12"
   1 => "3"
 ]
```

]

here is model

```
protected $fillable = ['email', 'phone', 'alert_level', 'client_id', 
   'salescenter_id', 'location_id', 'added_by', 'added_for_client', 'type'];
```

Comment: please add info after `var_dump($requestData)` to show the full array definition

Comment: array:6 [▼
         "_token" => "sTUoBilbfwZfp0x6tSdZhB4S5YQTO7l0xlip0QzA"
         "clientId" => "102"
        "fid" => array:2 [▶]
            "edit_email" => array:2 [▼
               0 => "van@gmail.com"
              1 => "demo@gmail.com"
        ]
     "edit_email_alert_level" => array:2 [▼
           0 => "sclocation"
           1 => "client"
       ]
     "edit_locations" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "12"
         1 => "3"
        ]
    ]

@V-K

Comment: just edit your post and add it there

Comment: attach also `FraudAlert` model

Comment: remove whereIn use where and pass $requestData['fid'] init

Comment: @GauravGupta the error says there is not field

Comment: @GauravGupta in foreach loop or after foreach loop i use $requestData['fid']

Comment: @V-K in error they have a return query too please provide that

Comment: @VandanMakwana all seems good, the last one add `dd($editrow)` before updating

Comment: @V-K
 array:6 [▼

  "email" => "van@gmail.com"

  "phone" => null

  "alert_level" => "client"

  "client_id" => null

  "salescenter_id" => null

  "location_id" => null

]

only first record display and when i dd in after foreach then display last record

Comment: use var_dump, place it before the  `FraudAlert::whereIn('id',$ids)->update($editrow)`, because `dd` stop the script but `var_dump` not. And the attach the last record

Comment: @V-K
Array ( [email] => van@gmail.com [phone] => [alert_level] => client [client_id] => 2022,2023 [salescenter_id] => [location_id] => )

Comment: hmm, `Unknown column '0' in 'field` this error usually points to wrong updating data, but data provided by you seems good...

Comment: @VandanMakwana try the below answer code if that resolves your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code update data individual entries:-

```
if(!empty($requestData['edit_email']) && count($requestData['edit_email']) > 0){
    foreach($requestData['edit_email'] as $i => $list){

           $ids = $requestData['fid'][$i]; //current id
           $editdata = array();
           $editrow['email']=$requestData['edit_email'][$i];
           $editrow['phone'] = NULL;

           switch($requestData['edit_email_alert_level'][$i]){
              case 'client':
                   $editrow['alert_level'] = "client";
                   $editrow['client_id'] = (!empty($requestData['edit_locations'])) ? implode("," ,$requestData['edit_locations']) : NULL;
                   $editrow['salescenter_id'] = NULL;
                   $editrow['location_id'] = NULL; 
                   break;
              case 'salescenter':
                   $editrow['alert_level'] = "salescenter";
                   $editrow['client_id'] = NULL;
                   $editrow['salescenter_id'] = (!empty($requestData['edit_locations'])) ? implode("," ,$requestData['edit_locations']) : NULL;
                   $editrow['location_id'] = NULL;
                   break;
              case 'sclocation':
                   $editrow['alert_level'] = "sclocation";
                   $editrow['location_id'] = (!empty($requestData['edit_locations'])) ? implode("," ,$requestData['edit_locations']) : NULL; 
                   $editrow['client_id'] = NULL;
                   $editrow['salescenter_id'] = NULL;                            
                   break;
              default:
                   break;
             }                                  
          FraudAlert::where('id',$ids)->update($editrow);
      }          
  }
```

the problem with your code is you are update data in both entries but the data is the same for both rows.

Comment: The creator of this topic haven't said the records can't have the same data

Comment: please read 1st line of this question when he runs his code in both id same record has been updated.

Comment: @GauravGupta i try above code to when i change only one data then updated all data same value

Comment: didn't get you "updated all data same value"? you mean $requestData has 2 fids it updates both with same data

Comment: please come here for further talk and tag me in the room when you arrive https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117924/laravel-documentation-introduction-to-laravel